# Insert Multiple Records faster way

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. My database has two tables.

**Member**

- MemberId
- RegCode
- BrokerCode
- Name

**TestInstallment**

- RegCode
- Amount
- Date
- InstallmentNo

In both tables there are many columns but I display here some of columns. `TestInstallment` is the table in which I import data from Excel and do some calculation. `Member` table contains rows with unique `RegCode` and `TestInstallment` contains multiple rows with same `RegCode`. For example, in `member` table there is only one row with `RegCode 'A105'` so `TestInstallment` contains approx 30 rows with `RegCode 'A105'`.

My final table is **Installment**

- InstallmentId
- MemberId
- Amount
- Date
- InstallmentNo

Now I want to insert rows of `TestInstallment` into `Installment` with reference of `MemberId`. Currently I am doing it using a cursor but it takes much time.

Currently in my database `Member` table has approx 47000 rows and `TestInstallment` has approx 700000 rows.

So how can I do this faster way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed installmentid is identity field.

```
insert into installment
select m.memberid, t.amount, t.date, t.installmentno,
from member m inner join testinstallment t on m.regcode = t.regcode
```